# AgGrid Dragging Rows between Grids with max limit

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am trying the example at the below link (Dragging Multiple Records Between Grids) within my React application https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-dragging-to-grid/

Below is my AgGrid

```
<MyAgGrid
  style={{ height: '100%' }}
  defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
  getRowId={getRowId}
  rowDragManaged={true}
  animateRows={true}
  //rowSelection={id === 0 ? 'multiple' : undefined}
  rowSelection={'multiple'}
  rowDragMultiRow={id === 0}
  suppressRowClickSelection={id === 0}
  suppressMoveWhenRowDragging={id === 0}
  rowData={id === 0 ? leftRowData : rightRowData}
  columnDefs={id === 0 ? leftColumns : rightColumns}
  onGridReady={(params) => onGridReady2(params, id)}
  frameworkComponents={{DeleteRenderer: DeleteRenderer}}
/>
```

Below is the other code;

```
const [leftApi, setLeftApi] = useState(null);
const [leftColumnApi, setLeftColumnApi] = useState(null);
const [rightApi, setRightApi] = useState(null);
const [rawData, setRawData] = useState([]);
const [leftRowData, setLeftRowData] = useState(null);
const [rightRowData, setRightRowData] = useState([]);
const [radioChecked, setRadioChecked] = useState(0);
const [checkBoxSelected, setCheckBoxSelected] = useState(true);

const DeleteRenderer = (props) => {
    console.log("DeleteRenderer ::::::::::::::: " + props);
    const handleDeleteRow = () => {
        // remove right grid data
        var rrd = [...props.rightRowData];
        rrd = rrd.filter((d) => d.personId !== props.node.data.personId);
        props.setRightRowData(rrd);
        props.api.applyTransaction({ remove: [props.node.data] });
    }
    return (
        <Icon onClick={handleDeleteRow} name="delete" size={15} />
    );
};

const leftColumns = [{
    rowDrag: true,
    maxWidth: 50,
    suppressMenu: true,
    rowDragText: (params, dragItemCount) => {
        if (dragItemCount > 1) {
            return dragItemCount + ' persons';
        }
        return params.rowNode.data.myName;
    },
}, {
    colId: 'checkbox',
    maxWidth: 50,
    checkboxSelection: true,
    suppressMenu: true,
    headerCheckboxSelection: true,
}, {
    field: 'myName'
}, {
    field: 'myEmail'
}, ];

const defaultColDef = {
  flex: 1,
  minWidth: 100,
  sortable: true,
  filter: true,
  resizable: true,
};

const rightColumns = useMemo(
    () => [{
        rowDrag: true,
        maxWidth: 50,
        suppressMenu: true,
        rowDragText: (params, dragItemCount) => {
            if (dragItemCount > 1) {
                return dragItemCount + ' persons';
            }
            return params.rowNode.data.myName;
        },
    }, {
        field: 'myName'
    }, {
        field: 'myEmail'
    }, {
        suppressMenu: true,
        maxWidth: 50,
        cellRenderer: 'DeleteRenderer', // Passing as string fixes the 'appendChild' error on dragging for the 1st time
        // pass rightRowData and setRightRowData as cellRendererParams
        cellRendererParams: {
            rightRowData: rightRowData,
            setRightRowData: setRightRowData,
        }
    }],
    [rightRowData, setRightRowData]
);

const loadGrids = useCallback(() => {
        setLeftRowData([...rawData]);
        setRightRowData([]);
        leftApi.deselectAll();
    }, [leftApi, rawData]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (rawData.length) {
      loadGrids();
    }
}, [rawData, loadGrids]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (leftColumnApi && leftApi) {
      leftColumnApi.setColumnVisible('checkbox', checkBoxSelected);
      leftApi.setSuppressRowClickSelection(checkBoxSelected);
    }
}, [leftColumnApi, leftApi, checkBoxSelected]);


const frameworkComponents = () => {
        return {DeleteRenderer: DeleteRenderer}
    }

    const getRowId = (params) => {
        return params.data.personId;
    }

    const onDragStop = useCallback(
        (params) => {
            var data = [...rightRowData];
            var nodes = params.nodes;

            // allow only if we have 3 rows or less in the right grid
            if (data.length < 4) {
                if (radioChecked === 0) {
                    var allowed = 4 - data.length;

                    leftApi.applyTransaction({
                        remove: nodes.slice(0, allowed).map(function(node) {
                            return node.data;
                        }),
                    });
                } else if (radioChecked === 1) {
                    leftApi.setNodesSelected({
                        nodes,
                        newValue: false
                    });
                }

                nodes.map(function(node) {
                    if (data.length < 4) {
                        data.push(node.data);
                    }
                });
            }

            console.log("::::::::::::::DATA::::::::::::::::" + data); // LOGS 4 rows max even after dragging more rows, though right grid displays additional rows (i.e. > 4)
            setRightRowData(data);
        },
        [leftApi, rightRowData, radioChecked]
    );

useEffect(() => {
    if (!leftApi || !rightApi) {
      return;
    }
    const dropZoneParams = rightApi.getRowDropZoneParams({ onDragStop });

    leftApi.removeRowDropZone(dropZoneParams);
    leftApi.addRowDropZone(dropZoneParams);
}, [leftApi, rightApi, onDragStop]);

const onGridReady2 = (params, side) => {
    if (side === 0) {
      setLeftApi(params.api);
      setLeftColumnApi(params.columnApi);
    }

    if (side === 1) {
      setRightApi(params.api);
    }
};
```

I want only 3 rows max to be allowed to be dragged to the right grid.
So in my "onDragStop", I am checking for data.length < 4.

However the issue is that the grid does not seem to be respecting the condition (data.length < 4) and I can see more than 3 rows getting added to the right grid.

Strangely though, the moment I hit Delete on the right for any row (say when it is displaying 7 rows), it kind of auto-corrects and shows (4-1) = 3 rows

Not sure if there is anything to do with "applyTransaction"

**UPDATED**

I have to do applyTransaction with "remove" to not reflect duplicate rows on the right.

```
const onDragStop = useCallback(
            (params) => {
                var data = [...rightRowData];
    
                var nodes = params.nodes;
                if (data.length < 4) {
                    nodes.map(function(node) {
                        console.log('node', node);
                        console.log('data', data);
                        if (data.length < 4) {
                            if (!data.some((d) => d.contactId === node.data.contactId)) {
                                data.push(node.data);
                            } else {
rightApi.applyTransaction({ remove: [node.data] }); //ADDED
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                setRightRowData(data);
            },
            [leftApi, rightRowData/*, radioChecked*/]
        );
```

Comment: Please try to return params.data.myName in your getRowId method

Comment: Trued returning params.data.myName in getRowId method...still able to add more rows

Comment: frameworkComponents, I don't have this in my example. I guess your ag-grid version is not up to date and that's why you use it to make it work.

Comment: Hey, check my example again. Some of my methods and definitions (renderer, defaultColDef, leftColumns) are outside of my function based component (outside of GridExample)

Comment: Oh k...yeah, I also have DeleteRenderer, leftColumns, defaultColDef defined outside the React component...so need to check how it is diff from yours...Also i am on AgGrid v 25.0.0

Comment: @AhmetFiratKeler : Are you able to try out your code using the same version 25.0.0 which I have....just in case, the version is the issue.....

Comment: Alternately, is there any way to say block/disable the 'Move' icon on the left once the limit is reached for the right grid AND re-enable if rows are deleted on the right and thus fall below the limit

Comment: Actually I just tried this for the "leftColumns" and it seems to be working .i.e. disabling dragging on left grid after adding 4 rows....
rowDrag: params => rightRowData.length < 4,

Comment: But now, I want to keep the options as it is on the left after dragging i.e. I want radioChecked = 1 and the moment I do that, I get an error saying "leftApi.setNodesSelected is not a function"

Comment: I have an answer for this

Answer (score 1):

So you want to keep the rows on the left, please modify onDragStop method like that

```
  const onDragStop = useCallback(
    (params) => {
      var data = [...rightRowData];

      var nodes = params.nodes;
      if (data.length < 4) {
        if (radioChecked === 1) {
          leftApi.setNodesSelected({ nodes, newValue: false });
        }

        nodes.map(function (node) {
          console.log('node', node);
          console.log('data', data);
          if (data.length < 4) {
            if (!data.some((d) => d.athlete === node.data.athlete))
              data.push(node.data);
          }
        });
      }

      setRightRowData(data);
    },
    [leftApi, rightRowData, radioChecked]
  );
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/7EIkWpRMYa04SAOU

Comment: Thanks...Say if I want to keep it simple and do not want checkbox and so do not need support for dragging multiple rows at a time...Would that mean some of the code changes like setNodesSelected can be done away with in onDragStop ?

Comment: Yes, you can remove checkbox from leftColumns and do away with "if (radioChecked === 1)" condition in onDragStop

Comment: Cool Awesome....and lastly just wanted to clarify what this condition is handling exactly........if (!data.some((d) => d.athlete === node.data.athlete)) {}

Comment: Believe the inner condition is redundant i.e. if (data.length < 4) {}....since we already have it above....

Comment: To prevent duplicate records, I've used this line: if (!data.some((d) => d.athlete === node.data.athlete)) {}

Comment: Inner condition is necessary: if (data.length < 4) {} Because we modify data while iterating over the nodes

Comment: Oh k...BTW, Now that I keep the left grid as it is, if I drag the same row to the right e.g. Athelete 1, the right grid displays this duplicate "Athelete 1" row twice...though say if there are 4 rows (3 unique + 1 duplicate "Athelete 1" row ) and now if I drag one more unique row say "Athelete 6", the right grid auto-corrects i.e. removes the earlier duplicate "Athelete 1" row....So want to avoid adding duplicate rows from being displayed at all in the right grid

Comment: I have added UPDATED code in the original question...So basically need to do applyTransaction with "remove" to not reflect duplicate rows on the right.

Hope there are no issues with that. Could you please confirm on that

Comment: You do not need this line -> rightApi.applyTransaction({ remove: [node.data] }); Why? Because we set right grid data iterating over nodes and constructing data array.

Comment: You check 'contactId' to prevent duplicate records as I see. Do you have a column for this in your leftColumns array?

Comment: Here's a modified version: https://plnkr.co/edit/bQtRDZ513n32hCWa?preview In this one, I've injected an id field into the column definitions and used it to prevent duplicate records.

Comment: Is your problem being able to drag and drop the same row now?

Comment: Yeah right...dragging and preventing duplicate rows to the right was the problem for which I had to explicitly add this code rightApi.applyTransaction({ remove: [node.data] })

......This works, though not sure if there is any side effect to it

Comment: Btw...I already have a row data attribute contactId for uniqueness....but not sure how i can leverage that...Is data[i]['id'] the only code change in your updated plnkr link ?

Comment: And getRowId method and data comparing in onDragStop

Comment: Actually I already have my unique "contactId" returned from my getRowId  and also the comparision with contactId in onDragStop....However without adding the "applyTransaction" code, it adds the duplicate i.e. I need to add..........rightApi.applyTransaction({ remove: [node.data] })

Comment: So what's the problem now? We can continue in chat.

Comment: Yeah with whatever I have tested so far with rightApi.applyTransaction({ remove: [node.data] })..........I did not find any problem.....but just wanted to confirm if you see any potential issue with this code OR does it seem good to you ?

Comment: I say it is not necessary and something different should be interfering with your code. I need more details from you.

Comment: I have added most of the code already in my original question...You can again go through the same...Only thing I am thinking is the ag-grid version which is v25.0.0 in my case